# Can Liquibase be used only to validate that ChangeSets have been applied but not actually execute them?

Tags: java, liquibase

I have a constraint for my production system that all SQL changes must be executed manually by a DBA for security purposes.  Consequently, I want to use Liquibase to generate the SQL, and have the DBA execute it.

However, on application startup in Production, I would like to configure Liquibase to ensure that all changesets have been executed, and have the proper signatures.  If either any of the changesets have an invalid signature or have not been executed, I would like Liquibase to throw an exception (which I can then handle in my startup sequence).  Under no circumstances would i want Liquibase to update the DB when run in this environment.

In other environments, I would like to leave it to Liquibase to run in default configuration - that is validate that existing changesets have not been modified and execute any missing changesets.

Does Liquibase support this kind of configuration?  I've looked through the `liquibase.configuration.GlobalConfiguration` class, but do not see any config parameters that would provide this config.

Comment: Use `updateSQL` instead of `update` - that will just generate the SQL that would have been run: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html#database-update-commands

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how you run Liquibase from your application, so it is a bit hard to say exactly. I think you will want to use two different commands - one for production, and one for all other environments. In most environments, you use the `update` command. In production, you would need to use the `status` command which returns either a count of the number of undeployed changesets or a list of undeployed changesets.

Comment: Thanks; I actually run Liquibase through a context listener, explicitly calling `new Liquibase(...).update(...)`.  Your answer pointed me in the right direction, however, and I see there are methods for `listUnrunChangeSets()` as well as `listUnexpectedChangeSets()`, although I'm not quite sure I understand what an 'UnexpectedChangeSet' is.

Comment: When Liquibase compares two databases A and B, where A is the 'target' (what needs to be updated) and B is the 'reference' (has all the changes desired), if there is something on A but not B, then Liquibase calls that an Unexpected change, and if it is on B but not A then it is a Missing change. In this case, the 'reference' is the changelog and the target is the actual database you are updating.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped my design.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Liquibase-CDI addon that supports this functionality.  It is based on the liquibase-cdi extension, but uses the CDI observer pattern instead.  It can be found on github at https://github.com/benze/liquibase-cdi